# Partial string matching using XPath

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

I'm working on a VBA script to get data from a xml document. I need help to modify my XPath code to search for a partial string instead of the whole one.
This is my current expression:

```
xmlhttpResponse.SelectNodes("/CharacteristicList/Characteristic[Name='ZCOMP_A_03']
                        /ComplexValueList/ValueItem/Value").Item(0).text
```

What I would like to do is something like this `[Name='ZCOMP_A_']`, but it doesn't seems to exist or to work like this. I saw some codes with starts-with and contains, but I would like to use a XPath similar with the one already used (if possible).

This is part of the XML code.

```
<CharacteristicList>
   <Characteristic>
      <Name>ZCOMP_A_03</Name>
      <ValueList>
         <ValueItem>
            <Value>10.50</Value>
```

**Update 1!**
I made some changes according to kjhughes, but I'm getting a "Unknown method" error.
This is the updated code:

```
Dim xmlhttpRequest As New MSXML2.xmlhttp
Dim xmlhttpResponse As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlhttpResponse.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

  Envelope = Envelope & "</soapenv:Envelope>"


  xmlhttpRequest.Open "POST", "http://website.xyz"
  xmlhttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
  xmlhttpRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://website2.xyz"

  xmlhttpRequest.send Envelope

  Set xmlhttpResponse = xmlhttpRequest.responseXML
  'Lenght_1 = xmlhttpResponse.SelectNodes("//Characteristic[Name='ZCOMP_A_03']/ComplexValueList/ValueItem/Value").Item(0).text Previous version
   Lenght_2 = xmlhttpResponse.SelectNodes("//Characteristic[starts-with(Name,'ZCOMP_A_')]/ComplexValueList/ValueItem/Value").Item(0).text
```

Comment: Perhaps vba doesn't support the way you expect otherwise `SelectNodes("//Characteristic//Name[contains(.,'ZCOMP_A_')]")(0).Text` this expression should bring you the desired results.

Comment: @SIM, I tried your suggestion, but it returns to me "Object is obrigatory". I'm trying some changes to solve this

Answer (score 2):

> What I would like to do is something like this `[Name='ZCOMP_A_']`, but
>   it doesn't seems to exist or to work like this. I saw some codes with
>   starts-with and contains, but I would like to use a xpath similar with
>   the one already used (if possible).

`Characteristic[Name='ZCOMP_A_']` selects for `Characteristic` elements with a `Name` child whose string value ***equals*** `ZCOMP_A_`.

If you want it to start with that string instead, use

```
Characteristic[starts-with(Name,'ZCOMP_A_')]
```

If you want it to appear anywhere within that string, use

```
Characteristic[contains(Name,'ZCOMP_A_')]
```

No, there is no shortened form that does either function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting an "Unknown method" when trying to use them. Do I need to do something else to get it working?

Comment: Edit your question and add your ***exact*** updated function call so that we can see what you've done.   The XPath advice given in this answer is correct, so your problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. If this is what you wanted to try:

```
Sub DemoXML()
    Dim XDoc As New DOMDocument, elem As Object, strXML As String

    strXML = "<CharacteristicList><Characteristic><Name>ZCOMP_A_03</Name><ValueList><ValueItem><Value>10.50</Value></ValueItem></ValueList></Characteristic></CharacteristicList>"
    XDoc.LoadXML (strXML)

    For Each elem In XDoc.SelectNodes("//Characteristic")
        [A1] = elem.SelectNodes(".//Name")(0).Text
        [B1] = elem.SelectNodes(".//Value")(0).Text
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft XML V6.0
```

Result:

```
ZCOMP_A_03
10.5
```